# Is there some guideline that I can point to about the overuse of bold and underline?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, email

I am getting really tired of getting emails and PowerPoint presentations in which half of the words bold and underlined. There is also excessive use of exclamation points, all caps, and overly strong wording.

I would like to send them a link to someplace authoritative that states that their writing style is tacky. Is there anything like that out there?  I would even settle for a blog post somewhere so long as it argues the point well.

Comment: This is probably more a question for [writers.se](http://writers.stackexchange.com) than here.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't know Swedish

Comment: hehe! My apologies. I was being lazy :| By .se, I meant .stackexchange.com. I've added in a link for clarity.

Comment: This question does not have an authoritative answer: it is a matter of opinion and taste. As such it is off topic here. Guidance on how and when to use bolding, underlining, capitalization, etc., will be found in various style guides, and these style guides do not agree. If you would like to find a styleguide with which you agree, google [ `powerpoint styleguide` ] and pick the one that suits your purpose.

Comment: Fundamental rule: If everything is ***important*** then nothing is important.

Comment: Re-posted here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6418/is-there-some-guideline-that-i-can-point-to-about-the-overuse-of-bold-and-underl

Comment: I have no idea why this question wasn't simply migrated over ... but, in any event, good luck :)